# Visual Studio Team Services - Release fails due to invalid credentials

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I have a problem with my Visual Studio Team Services deployment which has suddenly started to manifest.

The error occurs when the Deploy AzureRM App Service task tries to perform the MSDeploy call.

It seems to be a problem with the credentials used for MSdeploy but I cannot figure out where these need to be updated in Visual Studio team services.

We have a connection to Azure from there with a Service endpoint so my understanding was that build agent would download the publish settings and use those.

This only occurs in one deployment slot too. I have tried reseting the publish profile everywhere I can think of, restarting the build agents, restarting the app service.

Can anyone tell me where I can set the username and password?

Here is the log message, if that is any help.

> 2017-09-25T11:44:10.2830856Z [command]"C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft
>   Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe" -verb:sync
>   -source:package='Z:\ag-1_work\r2\a\my-backend\drop\My.Api.zip' -dest:auto,ComputerName='https://anon.publish.azurewebsites.windows.net:443/msdeploy.axd?site=myapi',UserName='********',Password='********',AuthType='Basic'
>   -setParam:name='IIS Web Application Name',value='anon' -userAgent:VSTS_5665af40-4e80-439e-8d92-4807daa39ca8_release_3_1348_11852_4
>   2017-09-25T11:44:10.5956009Z Info: Using ID
>   '27a108ac-8e86-41a8-beb4-e3bd3a27c220' for connections to the remote
>   server. 2017-09-25T11:44:11.1007371Z ##[error]Failed to deploy App
>   Service. 2017-09-25T11:44:11.1007371Z ##[error]Error Code:
>   ERROR_USER_UNAUTHORIZED

Comment: Can you access to `https://anon.publish.azurewebsites.windows.net` manually? And can you deploy succeed if changing another App service?

Comment: Was this ever solved? If so I would like to know how.

Comment: @Sam yes we did solve it, but I don't remember how! As I recall it just went away after restarting the build agent server...